How do I import TKinter to python if I use VS code?
I'm trying to import Tkinter into Python using VS code
I've already used the from Tkinter import * command but it seems to do nothing once I run it
Am I running it in the wrong place? Have I misspelt something? Are there more commands I need to run?
(I'm using Python 3.12.0 on Windows 10)

Hello and welcome to SO. What exactly do you expect to happen after running this? Or do you have more code that you have not shown?

Hi
I'm just trying to get Tkinter downloaded so that I can use it for later project atm
Im also testing it by using root=Tk( ) to see if it makes a new window, which it's not

I've also ran 'import tkinter print("the imported file is, tkinter.file)' to make sure that the file for the Tkinter modules itself has been imported, which it is. So what I'm confused about is, how come when I then run 'root=Tk( )' or anything that I should be able to run, it doesn't run???

Sorry for not mentioning this earlier (I completely forgot that it'd be necessary info) but I'm using VS code in Windows

When you write code on an IDE (such as vscode), the IDE, most probably, creates a Virtual Environment (venv). So the python you run on a command line and the python that runs on the IDE wont be the same. Make sure you installed the library in your venv.

@MSH VS Code is not an IDE, and in any case it does not automatically create virtual environments.

@JRiggles I didn't know it does not create a virtual environment. But VS Code is an IDE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code

@MSH I may just be arguing semantics, but I take your point! Though...arguing semantics is a programmer's bread and butter.

Valer's answer should do the trick.

A few things:

The module name is tkinter, not Tkinter (these names are case-sensitive)
Just running the code from tkinter import * won't cause anything noticeable to happen. You've imported tkinter, but you haven't done anything else with it.

Here's a very minimal example tkinter app that will pop up a window with some text on it
# this is the typical way to import tkinter; star imports should be avoided
import tkinter as tk  

# "instantiate" the Tk class - this is your main app instance
root = tk.Tk()  # root is just a name, but it's the one most people use
# 'tk' above refers to the alias we gave 'tkinter' in the import statement
# Tk() is the base application class

# the 'geometry' property lets us set the size of our 'root' window
root.geometry('200x100')

# now let's create a 'Label' widget that's a child of our 'root' window
label = tk.Label(root, text='Hello!')  # again 'label' is just a name
# 'pack()' is a 'geometry manager'; it tells our app to put this widget on the window
label.pack()

# lastly, to start our app we have to run the 'mainloop()'
root.mainloop()

I recommend following some tkinter tutorials to get started and familiarize yourself with the basic widget classes and the typical structure of a tkinter app.

Try importing tkinter like this:
import tkinter as tk

In Python 3.x, the tkinter module's name starts with a lowercase letter, unlike in Python 2.x.
Also, avoid using wildcard imports, as they can make code less readable and prone to conflicts. Instead, just import tkinter as tk and use the tk prefix.

Have you tried installing the compatible version of VS code and Tkinter?
If so then please check whether the version of Tkinter is updated and also try to run the command on cmd if, it is running on the system then your Tkinter is fine else uninstall vs-code and re-install it.
It will work fine.

Hi, thanks for answering so quick

I'm using the latest versions of both Tkinter and VS code so i don't think that's a problem
How would I check if Tkinter is updated?

Also, I've  ran 'import tkinter print("the imported file is, tkinter.file)' to make sure that the file for the Tkinter modules itself has been imported, which it is. So what I'm confused about is that when I run smth like 'root=Tk( ) it doesn't do anything?

Sorry for not mentioning this earlier (I completely forgot that it'd be necessary info) but I'm using VS code in Windows

This looks like a completely made up guess: (a) VSCode and Tkinter can't be compatible or incompatible. That doesn't make any sense. (b) Tkinter doesn't get "updated" on its own. It comes with Python and needs to be compiled against an installed version of Python. Telling OP to upgrade it is nonsensical.
